# Java error: <identifier> expected unable to compile

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to finish a homework assignment and keep getting two errors and cannot figure out how to fix them. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GoughAndreaProg5
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a password that meets the following rules: ");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Is atleast 8 characters long");
        System.out.println("Contains atleast 1 lower letter character");
        System.out.println("Contains atleast 1 upper letter character");
        System.out.println("Contains atleast 1 numeric digit");
        System.out.println("Contains atleast 1 special character from the set: !@#$%^&*");
        System.out.println("Does not contain the word \"and\" or the word \"end\"");
        System.out.println("");
        String myInput = stdIn.nextLine();

        boolean digit = false;
        boolean upperCase = false;
        boolean lowerCase = false;
        for(int x=0; x<myInput.length(); x++)
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(myInput.charAt(x)))
                digit = true;
            if(Character.isUpperCase(myInput.charAt(x)))
                upperCase = true;
            if(Character.isLowerCase(myInput.charA(x)))
                lowerCase = true;
        }
        boolean validLength = true;
        if (myInput.length() < 8)
        {
            System.out.println("Must be at least 8 characters long");
            validLength = false;
        }

        boolean special = false;
            if(myInput.indexOf('!') != -1 | myInput.indexOf('@') != -1 || myInput.indexOf('#') != -1 || myInput.indexOf('$') != -1 || myInput.indexOf('%') != -1 || myInput.indexOf('^') != -1 || myInput.indexOf('&') != -1 || myInput.indexOf('*') != -1)
                    special = true;
            else  //no special character
            {
                System.out.println("Must contain a special character");
            }

            boolean word = false;
            if (myInput.indexOf("and") != -1 || myInput.indexOf("end"));
            {
                word = true;
                System.out.println("Contains the string \"and\" or the word \"end\"");
            }
            if(!digit)
                System.out.println("Must have a numeric digit");
            if(!upperCase)
                System.out.println("Must have an upper case");
            if(!lowerCase)
                System.out.println("Must hava a lower case");

            //output valid or not
            if (validLength && special && !word && upperCase && lowerCase && digit)
                System.out.println("valid");
            else
                System.out.println("not valid");

    } //end main method
    public static void System.out.println(String inStr)
    {
        System.out.println(inStr);
    }  //end of alt string print method

}  //end of class
```

The errors are:

```
C:\Users\gougha\Documents\Park\Java Class\myJavaPgms\GoughAndreaProg5.java:76: error: '(' expected
public static void System.out.println(String inStr)
                         ^
C:\Users\gougha\Documents\Park\Java Class\myJavaPgms\GoughAndreaProg5.java:76: error:     <identifier> expected
    public static void System.out.println(String inStr)
                                     ^
```

I have tried every thing I can think of.  I'm sure it's an easy fix, but this is all so new to me and I can't see it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several compile errors with your code

To start

```
public static void System.out.println(String inStr)
```

should be (though you don't use it so I suggest just remove this method)

```
public static void println(String inStr)
```

Then

```
    if (myInput.indexOf("and") != -1 || myInput.indexOf("end"));
```

should be

```
    if (myInput.indexOf("and") != -1 || myInput.indexOf("end") != -1);
```

Finally

```
    if(Character.isLowerCase(myInput.charA(x)))
```

should be

```
    if(Character.isLowerCase(myInput.charAt(x)))
```

Comment: I also needed to take off the ';' at the end of:    

    if (myInput.indexOf("and") != -1 || myInput.indexOf("end")!= -1)

because when checking it, it was printing it contained and or end even though it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create this method `public static void System.out.println(inStr)`. Infact the syntax is also wrong. You just need to provide a method name when you create it. Not the class name along with it.

```
// Not required at all
public static void System.out.println(String inStr)
{
    System.out.println(inStr);
}
```

`System.out.println()` is the inbuilt method to print values to the console. So just use `System.out.println(inStr)` in your main method, whenever you need to print something on the System's output console.